# What is matlab algorithm for A\B?

Tags: matlab, linear-equation

Which numerical algorithm is used in Matlab for solving set of linear equations when we use x=A\B? for example gauss jordan or LU method etc.?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best one!<sup>1</sup>

The flow chart [from the official documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt42oms) below shows how the algorithm is chosen for full matrices. The flow chart is a bit larger for [sparse matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt42omx).

[image]

<sup>1</sup>Hopefully this will result in the best algorithm.